# Visual studio - enabling optimization lead to crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I'm using visual studio 2012 on windows 8, and the 2012 november CTP.
When I run the release version of my c++ application with optimization enabled (/o2) it crashes.
It happens inside a std::vector (not the first time I use vectors though).
Stepping inside the code I found out that the second time I do a push_back, here:

```
1197 if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
1198     _Reserve(1);
```

if I follow _Reserve, the value of count from 1 becomes 17656451, resulting in an error later when he it calls reallocate (I have exceptions disabled).
When running in debug mode everything is fine. Also release mode with optimizations disabled is running fine.
Could it be because the compiler is a test release? I'm using some of the new features so I can't switch back and try.

edit:

Here is part of the code.
I have two structures:

```
struct Subtile
{
    int sequenceId;
    AnimationSequenceState sequenceState;
    XMFLOAT2 position;
};

struct Tile
{
    //int type;
    bool visible;
    bool walkable;

    int x, y;
    int height;
    XMFLOAT2 position;
    float depth;
    XMVECTOR color;

    std::vector<Subtile> subtiles;
};
```

And this function gets called from inside a loop when parsing a 2d map of a game from a lua file:

```
HRESULT Map::parseTile(LuaState& l, int ix, int iy, XMFLOAT2 pos)
{
    Tile tile;

    tile.visible = l.getBoolField(-1, parsing::MapTileVisible, true);
    tile.walkable = l.getBoolField(-1, parsing::MapTileWalkable, true);
    tile.height = l.getIntField(-1, parsing::MapTileHeight, 0);

    bool sync = l.getBoolField(-1, parsing::MapTileSync, true);

    tile.x = ix;
    tile.y = iy;

    tile.position.x = pos.x;
    tile.position.y = pos.y;
    tile.depth = -static_cast<float>(ix + iy);
    tile.color = XMVectorSet(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    l.pushString(parsing::MapTileSubtiles);
    l.getTable();
    {
        for(l.pushNil(); l.next(); l.pop())
        {
            Subtile subtile;
            subtile.sequenceId = l.toInt();
            _sequences[subtile.sequenceId].update(subtile.sequenceState);
            if(!sync)
            {
                subtile.sequenceState.elapsed = rand() % 1000; //一秒、適当に
            }
            tile.subtiles.push_back(subtile);
        }
    }
    l.pop();

    _tiles.push_back(tile); //second time crashes here

    return S_OK;
}
```

edit2:

Here is a more complete part of the code -> [LINK](http://pastebin.com/ep5Xs3b9)

I tried to localize the problem and here is what I found.
Removing the vector at line 113 seems to have no effect but, commenting the vector at line 18 (and the code that writes/read it) solves it somehow.
There's a catch though, now I get an error from line 297, where after loading all the tiles I sort them. This problem goes away by commenting the for loop at 288-292.
Anyway I still don't understand why.

Comment: If you're debugging a release build, note you have no guarantee if those values are *actually* what they say. I really doubt there's a bug in `std::vector<>`. Come up with a small code example we can all test and see, otherwise you're asking us to magically know your code base.

Comment: The Standard Library implementation is unchanged in the CTP (the CTP only contains new binaries for the compiler itself).  Note that using the Standard Library containers with exceptions disabled is not a good idea (what, exactly, do you mean by "I have exceptions disabled"?).  As for the crash, it is likely that your code is broken.  Can you provide a short, standalone repro that demonstrates the problem?  If not, it's really not possible for us to help you out.

Comment: if you are getting an exception out of STL library, then it is usually an indication of stack corruption via uninitialized variables or uninitialized pointers or access violation such as reaching out of index places in memory via pointers. And in release mode if you are getting such an exception you usually need to check the code running before that.

Comment: Sorry, I added some code. Thanks for the hints, I'm trying to find out the problem and I'll update as I find something new (I'm going to sleep now though ^^). For the exceptions, I meant that I turned off c++ exception handling.

Comment: You need to reduce the problem to the minimum amount of code that is required to reproduce it.  Chances are, in doing so, you'll discover what the problem is; otherwise, if you post a minimal repro here, we can probably help you diagnose it.

Comment: I shared my project, hope it helps.

Comment: @キキジキ Looking at the code you posted on pastebin, you use pointers without checking whether they are valid, you do not even initialize `_tileset` in the constructor. This is problably not related to the error you have right now, but if you start checking things like that, you might find a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Wimmel thanks for checking my code. The only 2 pointers that I use are sprite and tileset, but I already checked both, they are loaded correctly. What remains are some int/floats and the two vectors. hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the culprit.
I was storing a XMVECTOR (DirectX Math library) directly in the Tile structure.

The documentation explicitly states that doing so should be avoided.
So what I did is storing a XMFLOAT4 and loading it into a XMVECTOR when the value is needed.

I still don't understand why it gave access violation but, I suppose is a combination of the internal representation of the vector (in my case, __m128), the optimizations of the math library and the uninitialized move that happens inside std::vector?

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball reveals that you have an out-of-range buffer access in another variable stored nearby, which is corrupting the `std::vector`'s metadata.

Then I asked the magic 8 ball whether it could be a hardware failure caused by overclocking, but the response was "Unlikely."

Comment: Could you use your crystal ball on the actual project I attached? :]